# Have a div with the same height as a sibling image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a responsive design of a panel consisting of an image and another container with its own internal elements, both side-by-side.

I have a parent div and inside an img and another div tags. Those two children tags have are floated block with a width in % and that works.

The problem is, when I shrink the page, the img shrinks to respect the % width rule and so does its height and it should stay that way, but the div on the side doesn't change its height to be the same as the sibling image.

I wrapped them in another div and put the internal div at height: 100% in hope that would do the trick but nothing.

I'd like to get the right div to change its height according to the left image.

```css
.img-container {
    display: block;
    width: 59%;
    float: left;
}
    
img {
    width: 100%;
}

.product-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 41%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #e4d233;
}
      
.product-img {
    width: 45%
}
```

```html
<div class="imgProductContainer">
 <div class="img-container">
  <img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/running_shoes/running_shoes_PNG5815.png"/>
 </div>
 <div class="product-container">
  <img id="product2Img" class="product-img" src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/png-gym-shoes-shoe-away-hunger-is-a-partnering-program-where-footwear-is-turned-around-to-provide-an-eco-friendly-means-of-support-for-our-feeding-the-futures-programs-520.png">
  <p><span id="product2Name"></span><br>
  <span>2.00 €</span></p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have a fixed height set for the product-container div? Remove that and you should get what you are lookin for.

Comment: whoops! its one of my tries to solve the problem i forgot to keep out the post. Sadly, that still does not solve the problem, img-container and product-container have different height :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.imgProductContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /*
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  */
}

.img-container {
  width: 59%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.product-container {
  width: 41%;
  background-color: #e4d233;
}

.product-img {
  width: 45%
}
```

```html
<div class="imgProductContainer">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/running_shoes/running_shoes_PNG5815.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="product-container">
    <img id="product2Img" class="product-img" src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/png-gym-shoes-shoe-away-hunger-is-a-partnering-program-where-footwear-is-turned-around-to-provide-an-eco-friendly-means-of-support-for-our-feeding-the-futures-programs-520.png">
    <p><span id="product2Name"></span><br>
      <span>2.00 €</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

i guess thats how it should look like ?
i am not sure what .product-img class was for so i replaced productImg class with it.

i also removed all floats an just made the main container a flex box with its child aligned, you should look deeper into flexbox if you want something else here.

hope it helps

Comment: yes, that class like that was a mistake, but still my end result would be .img-container and .product-container having the same height, based on the height of the left image that changes when the page shrinkens, and your code doesn't seem to be what i was looking for, hope it's more clear now

Comment: i edited my answer,. i just commented out 2 lines at the very top and now both divs are the same height based on which is heigher

Comment: @Dirk `// ...` isn't a valid comment in `CSS`, the only way to make a comment in `CSS` is by using `/* ... */`.

Comment: It would be great if you edit your answer replacing the wrong comments.

Comment: sure no problem

Answer (score 0):

You can force equal height for the containers using CSS Grid:

```css
.img-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
    
img {
    width: 100%;
}
.imgProductContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.product-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #e4d233;
}
      
.product-img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgProductContainer">
 <div class="img-container">
  <img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/running_shoes/running_shoes_PNG5815.png"/>
 </div>
 <div class="product-container">
  <img id="product2Img" class="productImg" src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/png-gym-shoes-shoe-away-hunger-is-a-partnering-program-where-footwear-is-turned-around-to-provide-an-eco-friendly-means-of-support-for-our-feeding-the-futures-programs-520.png">
  <p><span id="product2Name"></span><br>
  <span>2.00 €</span></p>
 </div>
</div>
```